# Insufficient storage on tablet says it has 12gb used when only used 2

Tags: insufficient-memory, storage

My brother wants to download an app on his tablet yet it says he has insufficient storage so i went to his storage where it has picture then the amount it takes up and downloads and apps and so on yet when you count all these amounts its around 2 gb yet at the bottom it has 12 gb please help!!!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Download Terminal Emulator from play store, open and show the output of `df` command? That would help understanding your storage

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage). You may have to delete an app or an app's data  to get some space for the said apps' installation.

Comment: @Firelord the storage is : available=498mb, system reserved= 1.69gb, apps=1.05gb ,pictures videos = 72kb, audio=220kb, downloads=135mb, cached data=117mb, misc=91mb however when i click apps it says at the bottom "12gb used 609mb free"

Comment: @JCurry make sure you've read our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to get an idea how to interpret "storage". Then [edit] your question and add how much all/used/free ***internal*** storage there is on your tablet. While [edit]ing: Please see to give it some structure (punctuation, paragraphs) to make it easier to read :)

Comment: sorry @Firelord im new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the android app storage quota is like 1 GB, What version of android are you running? and what is the exact model of the device?

If its 4 and up you can easily move the apps to usb storage and gain more space, to do that you need to go to applications on your settings, click on the apps and then click move to sd. after you do that, reboot the device and you will have more storage for more apps.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have facing this issue while downloading apps from play store folllow this steps.
Settings->apps->all apps.
Clear data of Play store, Play service, 
If the problem still persists, clear the data of all web browsers in the same way.
Try to find app which use memory more than usual.